# Logical Indexing of 3D matrix on basis of a 1D matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a *450*-by-*1000*-by-*3* double in Matlab, which consists of 19 unique values that are obviously repeated a lot of times. Let's call this `A`.

Let's pretend that some of these numbers are 10, 20 and 30. I store those numbers in `B`, such that B is *3*-by-*1*.

Now, I really, really would like to spit out a new matrix with the same dimensions as `A` (*450*-by-*1000*-by-*3*) but with `1` where I find 10, 20 and 30, and `0` where it differs from these 3 numbers.

I've looked into both logical indexing and `find`, but I keep banging my head against the wall. Doing this with one number is easy, but doing it with an array somehow does not seem to work. Even with a loop.

Comment: use the [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1**: use [`ismember`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html),  as suggested by Dan:

```
result = ismember(A, B);
```

**Approach 2**: use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = any(bsxfun(@eq, A, reshape(B,1,1,1,[])), 4);
```

Comment: With `reshape` in 4th dimensions, `bsxfun` approach is very nice :)

Comment: Gah. That was glaringly simple. Thanks a lot.